# How to make perl exit with an error code upon use of uninitialized-value?

Tags: perl

I don't see how to make perl fail upon use of uninitialized-value. Is there a way to make this the default behavior? Thanks.

https://perlmaven.com/use-of-uninitialized-value

Comment: What have you tried so far? You didn't include any code, so it's impossible to know. Also, take a look at [`exit`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/exit).

Comment: I don’t know what to try. I want the program to fail instead of just giving a warning. This must be done with some kind of configuration of Perl at the beginning of a script. Exit won’t work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you're claiming isn't working.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#Fatal-Warnings

Comment: The link from @Shawn seems to be what you want.  But also see [Carp::Always](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Always)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings FATAL => qw[uninitialized];
use feature 'say';

my $foo;

say "Foo is $foo";
say "Don't get here";
```

Comment out the `FATAL` line to see the standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Dave's answer sure is the best pick for the described use case.

Here is another solution, that demonstrates the use of the warning signal handler (see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html).

The benefit of using a signal handler is flexibility : you can trap any kind of warning, analyze it and then implement any behavior you like. In the given use case this is an overkill, it but can be useful in more complex cases.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature "say";

local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    if ($_[0] =~ /^Use of uninitialized value/) {
        die $_[0]; 
    } else { 
        warn $_[0] ;
    }
};

my $foo;
say "Foo is $foo";
say "Dont get here";
```